# Ubuntu 12.04 Sound Settings shows "Dummy Output" after updates

Tags: drivers, sound, pulseaudio, intel

I had NOT installed any updates to Ubuntu 12.04 LTS since September 2013.  Today, I just updated ALL recommendations from the Update Manager.

My audio WAS working fine and now it is NOT working at all.  It doesn't detect my audio hardware.  When I go into "Sound Settings", I see only a Dummy Output device.

I have tried suggestions from several forums with no success, such as [*Speakers Don't Work in Ubuntu 12.04 (Dummy Output)*](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2099204).

Some diagnostic info:

```
[~] $ cat /proc/asound/cards
cat: /proc/asound/cards: No such file or directory


[~] $ lspci | grep -i audio
00:1b.0 Audio device: Intel Corporation 7 Series/C210 Series Chipset Family High Definition Audio Controller (rev 04)
```